# printing an array of chars ( C) Only first letter

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need to fill manually an array of chars. I declared it like this:

```
char* coor = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
```

Then I manually assigned every variable to its position:

```
coor[0] = O_colum;
coor[2] = ((char)(O_row+48));

coor[3] = '-';
coor[4] = D_colum;

coor[5] = ((char)(D_row+48));
```

(`D_Row` and `O_row` are integers, I need that number in character form, not the equivalent value in ASCII; that’s why I do `+48`)

The problem comes when I try to print it. If I use `printf(" %s", coor)` it only prints the first characters and I don’t know why. I’m using `%s`, so it should print all the characters in the string.
When I do this:

```
char *p = "hello";
printf("%s",p);
```

It does print `hello`.

Comment: Last index of a 5-element array is 4, not 5... and you're skipping element 1.  Also, you need a null byte at the end... so you should allocate 6 bytes and set the last to 0.

Comment: OMG thanks, fixed it, skipping element 1 was a problem when writting it here, but it was really the null byte that causes the problem! THANKS!

Comment: Note: `sizeof(char)` will never differ from `1` as that is defined by the standard. So nothing gained using it. If you want to always use the correct type, use `sizeof(*coor)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes in your code:

- you are skipping the position 1 of the array. This is probably the
  reason why it prints only the first element.
- you need to add the end string character `\0` in the end of the
  string.

This should fix it :

```
char* coor = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);

coor[0] = O_colum;
coor[1] = ((char)(O_row+48));

coor[2] = '-';
coor[3] = D_colum;

coor[4] = ((char)(D_row+48));
copr[5] = '\0';
```